# jQuery scrollable images

Tags: jquery, image

Can anyone point me to a jQuery plugin / script that can do what they do with the images here:
http://alignednyc.com/listings?cmd=details&id=

cheers,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're using the [jQuery Tools Scrollable plugin](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/gallery.html) (a few others as well, but I assume you're talking about the main gallery views).

[You can check out other demos here](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html#demos).